# ffmpeg says "Unknown encoder 'mp3'"

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg version 1.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 25 2013 23:22:43 with gcc 4.1.2 (GCC) 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)
  configuration: --enable-static --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-postproc --enable-libvpx --enable-libtheora
  libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
  libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
  libavformat    54. 59.106 / 54. 59.106
  libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
  libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
  libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/usr/local/httpd-2.2.25/htdocs/mvix/resources/testsp/mov01.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2011-04-25 22:07:51
    comment         : Encoded and delivered by apple.com/trailers/
    comment-eng     : Encoded and delivered by apple.com/trailers/
    copyright       : 漏 2011 Paramount Pictures. All Rights Reserved
    copyright-eng   : 漏 2011 Paramount Pictures. All Rights Reserved
    title           : Transformers: Dark of the Moon
    title-eng       : Transformers: Dark of the Moon
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Duration: 00:02:27.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5353 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x532, 5215 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 2997 tbn, 5994 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-04-25 22:07:51
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 132 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-04-25 22:07:51
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-04-25 22:07:51
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Please use -b:a or -b:v, -b is ambiguous
Unknown encoder 'mp3'
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says, there is no encoder named `mp3` in ffmpeg. There are various encoders for MP3. In ffmpeg you'd use `libmp3lame`.  See also the [MP3 encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encoding%20VBR%20%28Variable%20Bit%20Rate%29%20mp3%20audio).

Your build must be configured with `--enable-libmp3lame`. See [How to Compile FFmpeg on CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide) or simply use a [Linux build of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds). Either method will provide a build that supports `libmp3lame`.

You can check the available encoders with `ffmpeg -encoders`.

Also, check your syntax. While you haven't provided your actual command (you should always provide the command), note that `-b` as an option alone is ambiguous. If you want to specify video or audio bitrate, use `-b:v` or `-b:a`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install libavcodec-extra-XX.

Then in ffmpeg the option should be `-acodec libmp3lame` instead of `-acodec mp3`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can install the **pre-built ffmpeg** from [ffmpeg official recommendation](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg) in case of some inconsistency you can come across